# Multi-page Long Table Issues

Tags: longtable

I am trying to make a multipage long table in the landacape mode (and that too with textwrapping), however, the second row of the same doesn't start from the same page but rather migrates to the next page. Here is the minimum example:

```
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.45cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{6cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{9cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.45cm}}

    \toprule
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D}\\
    \midrule
    1 & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x &  1\\
    
    2 & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x &  2\\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

Is there a way that the second row starts from the same page and its remaining text moves to the next page?

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table, which reproduce your problem.  Y must be aware, that long table can be broken between pages only between nodes and that you required that tables content is vertically centered. For start replace `m{...}` column type with `p{....}` and compare result.

Comment: BTW, you also has error in prescribing third column type in table. It is sufficient to write `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{9cm}` and not `>{\centering\arraybackslash}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{9cm}`

Comment: Thanks for picking up the error in Column 3.

Comment: I have replaced m{...} with p{...}, however, it just finished the vertical alignment, however, the problem remains the same.

Comment: please post an example of the problem, we can not run your code as it is an incomplete fragment, and I do not see any problem with the image that you show, the page break has to be where it is as the third row is very large and would not fit on the first page as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

To long for the comment:

- It is not entirely clear what is your problem.
- You not provide any information about page layout of your document, so we can't check if your table can fit on your page
- Why you prescribe for the first and the last column 3.45cm width if their content are just single letter or number digits
- Using standard `article` document class, your table occupy about half of page.
- Are you avare, that long table can be broken between pages only between rows?
- in your comment you still claim that your problem stay the same, but what is your problem?

For example, how can your table looks (in case that instead of `longtable and used column types you use` xltabular`and`X` column type):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{c
                                >{\hsize=0.66\hsize}X
                                >{\hsize=1.34\hsize}X c}
    \toprule
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D}\\
    \midrule
    1 & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x &  1\\
\addlinespace
    2 & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x &  2\\
\addlinespace
  33 & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x & x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x &  33\\
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was not aware that a long table can only be broken down between rows. This is precisely where my question comes as i am looking for some way to break down within the same row. The values x here are merely dummy, i.e., i am playing with some significantly long text in all columns including the last column.